# Prevent click on next until all inputs are filled in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a multi-step form and save all the data in states. How can I prevent the 
click "next" until the user fills all the information?

Answer (score 0):

In render function enable "Next" button only if all data are entered.

```
<button type="button" disabled={this.state.props.name.length < 3 || .....}>Next</button>
```